# WooCommerce Stucked (?) - Edit dimensions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

After an update of woocommerce I cant change the product dimensions of the woocommerce catalog and my product's images on the product page is showing like this:
http://prntscr.com/ixegws
Before the last update it was propably fixed by going on WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display. but now in customize its asking on for width not for height. 
Can anyone help me? What I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be like that. 3.3 changes the way images work. Instead of setting a width and height you set a width and aspect ratio:

https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/12/11/wc-3-3-image-size-improvements/

So if you want square cropped images that are 300 pixels wide (for example), set the width to 300 and cropping to 1:1.

Comment: Yes but why my image is showing like this: http://prntscr.com/ixegws ?